# How to manage multiple positions in RecyclerView OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to know how I can get access to other elements of the array in this onclicklistener for a Recycler view. Specifically, I want to be able to change the enabled state of a position other than the current Listener position, but within the click event.

I'm trying to make it such that if three colors are checked (those are check boxes) every box not checked will be disabled until the number of boxes checked is < 3.

The for-loops I have I wrote make sense, but I can't programmatically change the enabled state within the onClickListener for some reason.

```
  private void buildRecyclerView() {

            mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);

            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(int position) {

                    boolean checkedState;

                    if (mExampleList.get(position).getChecked1() == false) {

                        checkedState = true;

                    } else {

                        checkedState = false;

                    }

                    changeItem(position, checkedState);

                    int sum = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {

                        Boolean checked = mExampleList.get(i).getChecked1();

                        if (checked == true) {

                            sum = sum + 1;

                        }

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {

                        Boolean checked = mExampleList.get(i).getChecked1();

                        if (!checked && sum == 3) {

                            mExampleList.get(i).setEnabled1(false);

                        } else {

                            mExampleList.get(i).setEnabled1(true);

                        }

                    }

                }

            });

        }
```

adapter

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            mCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (listener != null){

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION);
                        listener.onItemClick(position);

                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {

        mExampleList = exampleList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return evh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mCheckBox.setText(currentItem.getCheckText());
        holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(currentItem.getEnabled1());
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(currentItem.getChecked1());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mExampleList.size();

    }
}
```

Item Class

```
public class ExampleItem {

    public String mCheckText;
    public Boolean mEnabled;
    public Boolean mChecked;

    public ExampleItem(String mCheckText, Boolean mEnabled, Boolean mChecked) {

        this.mCheckText = mCheckText;
        this.mEnabled = mEnabled;
        this.mChecked = mChecked;
    }

    public ExampleItem(String mCheckText) {
        this.mCheckText = mCheckText;
    }

    public String getCheckText() {
        return mCheckText;
    }

    public void setCheckText(String mCheckText) {
        this.mCheckText = mCheckText;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled1() {
        return mEnabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled1(Boolean mEnabled) {
        this.mEnabled = mEnabled;
    }

    public Boolean getChecked1() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked1(Boolean mChecked) {
        this.mChecked = mChecked;
    }

}
```

[image]

In other words, I am trying to make everything below blue disabled until I uncheck Red, Green, or Blue!

Comment: Try to use `singleItemSelection` recyclerView

Comment: Easy way is add mAdapter.notifyDataSetChange in bottom callback onItemClick, you already set enable to data but view not notify

Comment: Thanks, Cong. I put that right below the for loops and nothing changed. I actually tried that before with just mExampleList.get(arbitrary position).setEnabled1(false); and mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(same arbitrary position); No luck. I can enable them in the onCreate but that is a one-time thing. I need it to be an onClick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

In adapter, add below codes:

```
private int selectedCount = 0;

public int getSelectedCount() {
    return selectedCount;
}

public void setSelectedCount(int selectedCount) {
    this.selectedCount = selectedCount;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and change **onBindViewHolder()** to:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    holder.mCheckBox.setText(currentItem.getCheckText());
    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(currentItem.getChecked1());
    if ((selectedCount == 3)) holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(currentItem.getChecked1());
    else holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Then in Activity/Fragment, change **mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener()...** to:

```
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            boolean checkedState;
            int selectedCount = mAdapter.getSelectedCount();

            if ((selectedCount != 3) || (mExampleList.get(position).getChecked1())) {
                if (mExampleList.get(position).getChecked1() == false) {
                    checkedState = true;
                    selectedCount++;
                } else {
                    checkedState = false;
                    selectedCount--;
                }
                changeItem(position, checkedState);
                mAdapter.setSelectedCount(selectedCount);
            }
        }
    });
```

Pls note that no need to have **mEnabled** field in the **ExampleItem** class. Hope that helps!

Explanantion:
About the onClick:- This is because CheckBox totally covered the layout, so **itemView** cannot recieve the click event. About RecyclerView:- The idea is simple, after modified the data **set** [not list, here I refer to the mExampleList and also the selectedCount], then call notifyDataSetChanged() which will redraw all recycler item views.

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately, it does not let me conditionally modify other parts of the list when clicking any other position. The onClickListener only lets you modify the particular position where the click event takes place. It doesn't let you go outside of that position and change other ViewState.

Comment: Are other CheckBoxes disabled after selected 3 items? Are CheckBoxes enabled after deselected item? Can new item be selected afterwards? I  think that there is no action when clicked an item with a disabled CheckBox, otherwise I don't know why the CheckBox is disabled.

Comment: The other checkboxes were not disabled, but that is what I want. While I can disable a particular box in the onCreate of the main activity, if I go to the mAdapter onClickListener in the Main Activity, mExampleList.get(3).setEnabled1 does not do anything. In fact, I can't even make a Toast in that onClick.

Comment: In the adapter, change `itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` to `mCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`.

Comment: @ i_A_mok !!! You the real jesus bro. It worked. Been trying to figure this out for a long time. Thank you! Could you perhaps give an explanation as to how it works and why it wasn't working before?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a setter function for your 'mExampleList' in your Adpater class, to update the dataset that the adapter is using. It obviously does not change anything, if you make changes to 'mExampleList' in your activity, without updating the list used by the Adapter.

So at the end of your click listener you would have something like that:

```
mAdapter.setExampleList(mExampleList)
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Thank you! Going to try to implement this somehow and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: This unfrotuantely did not seem to work: public void setExampleList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList) {
        this.mExampleList = mExampleList;
    } Placed into the adapter. Still can't update other parts of the list during click event.